# Is it possible to import/restore photo albums from an old, recently imported Library?

Tags: macos, photos.app, import, album

I recently helped a friend import a large, 541GB iPhoto library into Photos on Ventura.

The files were imported, but the photo albums were not.

Now we're wondering if there is a way to get the albums.

We have other Macs that are not using Ventura, but they do not have the disc space needed for this large import.